# MongoDB: Filter an array by _id using aggregate

Tags: mongodb

I need some help to filter the field Internals array to only show the item with the same _id of this field profile_id using aggregate, but I realy cant get this.

I try use filter, lookup and search in many posts.

I want using aggregate, to get the documents with filtered array of users based on the objectID of the profile.

**Every profile id has only one internal id**

Each user has only one INTERNAL.

[Mongo PLayGround Query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Kr69Bxr6u_m)

**PRODUCTS TABLE**

```
 [
      {
        "_id": {"$oid": "5dd5a66e8ddbd07fa251b88e"},
        "name": "Product One",
        "internals": [
          {
            "default": false,
            "_id": {"$oid": "5e94da0f4d499253049ec532"},
            "name": "Type A"
          },
          {
            "_id": {"$oid": "5e94da0f4d499253049ec534"},
            "name": "Type B"
          },
          {
            "_id": {"$oid": "5e94da0f4d499253049ec536"},
            "name": "Type C"
          },
          {
            "_id": {"$oid": "5e94da0f4d499253049ec538"},
            "name": "Type D"
          },
          {
            "_id": {"$oid": "5f05d9a2bfc8fa1361d8beea"},
            "name": "Type E"
          },
          {
            "_id": {"$oid": "5f05d9a2bfc8fa1361d8beec"},
            "name": "Type F"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id": {"$oid": "5e8b40bc91dd0e12e0219578"},
        "name": "Product Two",
        "internals": [
          {
            "_id": {"$oid": "5e8b40bc91dd0e12e0219579"},
            "name": "Default Type"
          }
        ],
      }
    ]
```

**USER TABLE**

```
[
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "603d4c44505a51001c9b936f"},
    "email": "mister.paper@papers.org",
    "name": "Mister Paper",
    "profile": {
      "products": [
        {
          "_id": {"$oid": "603d4d101c24a9001cf79db1"},
          "product": {"$oid": "5dd5a66e8ddbd07fa251b88e"},
          "profile": {"$oid": "5e94da0f4d499253049ec534"}
        },
        {
          "_id": {"$oid": "603fe3ebca063ea357ca0666"},
          "product": {"$oid": "5e8b40bc91dd0e12e0219578"},
          "profile": {"$oid": "5e8b40bc91dd0e12e0219579"}
        },
        {
          "_id": {"$oid": "603fe3ebca063ea357ca0667"},
          "product": {"$oid": "5dd5a66e8ddbd07fa251b88e"},
          "profile": {"$oid": "5e94da0f4d499253049ec538"}
        }
      ],
    },
    "username": "mister.paper@papers.org"
  }
]
```

That is my query at this moment after try many others :

**QUERY**

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
{ $match: { email: { $in: [ /mister.paper/i ] }} }, { $sort: { created_at: -1 } },

{$unwind:"$profile"},
{$unwind:"$profile.products"},
{$unwind:"$profile.products.profile"},

{'$lookup': { from: 'products', localField: 'profile.products.product', foreignField: '_id', as: 'products' } },
{$unwind:"$products"},
//{$unwind:"$products"},
//{$unwind:"$products.internals"},
{$addFields: { "products.profile_id": '$profile.products.profile'}},

{'$lookup': { from: 'products.internals', localField: 'products.profile_id', foreignField: '_id', as: 'internalsArray' } },

{
    '$project': {
    name: 1,
    products: {
      _id: "$products._id",
      name: "$products.name",
      profile_id : 1,
    },
    productsId: 1,
    "internals": { _id: "$products.internals._id" , name: "$products.internals.name" },
        internalsArray : 1,
    }
}
], {});
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: What I realy need is to get only the INTERNALS._ID that match with profile.products.profile (ObjectId) or profile_id ... this is very hard to do ... yes, I try $filter and $unwind

Comment: My user product has a profile id 5e94da0f4d499253049ec534
I want to get only the internal with the id 5e94da0f4d499253049ec534
for that user on that product

Comment: Can you provide the true shape of your documents. What you provided is the result of your query. For all the collections that are being used.

Comment: I can try, but I dont know if is a good idea put it here

Comment: That's why you should create a sample data for you collections that links together.

Comment: I reedit my question and put the sample data

Answer (score 1):

I used `$filter` to filter out products internal array by matching `internal._id` and `profile.products.profile`. You can extend this query to further shape your data in desired format.

Here's the core pipeline that performs filtration. I used it after your `{$unwind: "$products"}` stage.

```
{
    "$addFields": {
      "products.internals": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$products.internals",
          as: "internal",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$internal._id",
              "$profile.products.profile"
            ]
          },
          
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Mongo Playground:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/zPxE-H2mYc7

A suggestion after a brief look on your sample data is your first unwind `{$unwind:"$profile"}` and `{$unwind:"$profile.products.profile"}` doesn't make sense since profile is an object in first unwind and `ObjectId` in second unwind so you can remove them.